# Keep getting Nan value error when using keras with tensorboard

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am using python3 with conda, and running deep learning with keras over tensorflow and using tensorboard for logging of the model (I am using histograms)

I keep getting the following error:

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Nan in summary
>   histogram for: conv2d_1/kernel_0   [[node conv2d_1/kernel_0 (defined
>   at
>   /home/user/anaconda3/envs/siamese/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/callbacks.py:796)
>   = HistogramSummary[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](conv2d_1/kernel_0/tag,
>   conv2d_1/kernel/read/_139)]]

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39854390/nan-in-summary-histogram) that this is beacause tensorboard logging makes the nan values explicit.

I Tried to change [adagrad to Adam](https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/#!topic/discuss/cKq4b9jYiP8)
I tried to lower the learning rate 
I tried to clip the loss function values 
I tried to make the k.epsilon value higher (1e-4) 
I tried to add a small value to the predictions 
I changed the last layer's activation to sigmoid

Nothing seems to work...

This is my code

```
    def triplet_wrapper(y_true, y_pred):
        import keras.backend as k
        from tensorflow.math import l2_normalize
        y_pred = k.clip(y_pred, 1e-6, 1e1)
        return k.clip(metric_learning.triplet_semihard_loss(k.squeeze(y_true, 1) + 1e-7, l2_normalize(y_pred, epsilon=1e-7)), 1e-7, 1e1)


        keras.losses.custom_loss = triplet_wrapper
        model5 = Sequential()
        model5.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation="relu", input_shape=input_shape))
        model5.add(MaxPool2D((2, 2)))
        for i in range(layers - 1):
            model5.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation="relu"))
            model5.add(MaxPool2D((2, 2)))
        model5.add(Flatten())
        model5.add(Dropout(0.5))
        model5.add(Dense(100, activation="sigmoid"))
        model5.add(Dropout(0.5))
        model5.compile(loss=triplet_wrapper, optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0001))
```

I load the data using this normalized data loader

```
i = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0 / 255.0)
```

[This](https://www.kaggle.com/c/painter-by-numbers) is the dataset (It's large, I put the entire training set into a one directory - dataset and then run this script)