# Tensorflow Estimator training works on CPU, but terminates with NaN on GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, memory

I'm trying to train a model written in Tf (specifically this one: [Depth and Motion Learning](https://github.com/google-research/google-research/tree/master/depth_and_motion_learning)). It works just fine on CPU, but when I try to train it on GPU it uses up almost all of its memory no matter what batch size I set, and throws an error (not always the same) that may not because of the memory usage but that was my only guess on why the model would not train if I changed `CUDA_AVAILABLE_DEVICES`  from `-1` to `0`.

Some details:

- Tensorflow-gpu 1.15.0
- Tensorflow-graphics-gpu 1.0.0
- CUDA 10.0
- Tesla V100-DGXS-32GB
- Pthon 3.6.9

Things I tried to decrese GPU memory usage:

- Decreasing the batch size all the way to 1
- Overwriting the original run_config for the estimator with the `tf.GPUOptions`:

```
gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.05)
run_config = tf_estimator.RunConfig(**run_config_params).replace(session_config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options))
```

- Decreasing the size of the shuffling queue

None of the above mentioned attempts seemed to have any effect on the memory usage (still around 99%), and I get the same errors after the first few steps of the training as  before.

I'm pretty new to Tensorflow so I hope I wrote down everything that's relevant.

My main question is what could I do in order to make the training work? I also find it strange that I couldn't get the memory usage below 32gb. Is this normal?

Finally, here's the error message that I get about 80% of the runs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1365, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1350, in _run_fn
    target_list, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1443, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Nan in summary histogram for: PredictedDepth
     [[{{node PredictedDepth}}]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/root/workdir/code/depth_and_motion_learning/depth_motion_field_train.py", line 38, in <module>
    app.run(main)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 308, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 254, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/root/workdir/code/depth_and_motion_learning/depth_motion_field_train.py", line 34, in main
    depth_motion_field_model.get_vars_to_restore_fn)
  File "/root/workdir/code/depth_and_motion_learning/training_utils.py", line 324, in train
    vars_to_restore_fn)
  File "/root/workdir/code/depth_and_motion_learning/training_utils.py", line 276, in run_local_training
    input_fn=input_fn, max_steps=trainer_params.max_steps, hooks=[init_hook, wandb_hook])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 370, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1161, in _train_model
    return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1195, in _train_model_default
    saving_listeners)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1494, in _train_with_estimator_spec
    _, loss = mon_sess.run([estimator_spec.train_op, estimator_spec.loss])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 754, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1259, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1360, in run
    raise six.reraise(*original_exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/six.py", line 719, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1345, in run
    return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1418, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1176, in run
    return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 956, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1180, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1359, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1384, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Nan in summary histogram for: PredictedDepth
     [[node PredictedDepth (defined at usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1748) ]]

Original stack trace for 'PredictedDepth':
  File "usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "root/workdir/code/depth_and_motion_learning/depth_motion_field_train.py", line 38, in <module>
    app.run(main)
  File "usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 308, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 254, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "root/workdir/code/depth_and_motion_learning/depth_motion_field_train.py", line 34, in main
    depth_motion_field_model.get_vars_to_restore_fn)
  File "root/workdir/code/depth_and_motion_learning/training_utils.py", line 324, in train
    vars_to_restore_fn)
  File "root/workdir/code/depth_and_motion_learning/training_utils.py", line 276, in run_local_training
    input_fn=input_fn, max_steps=trainer_params.max_steps, hooks=[init_hook, wandb_hook])
  File "usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 370, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1161, in _train_model
    return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1191, in _train_model_default
    features, labels, ModeKeys.TRAIN, self.config)
  File "usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1149, in _call_model_fn
    model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
  File "root/workdir/code/depth_and_motion_learning/training_utils.py", line 251, in estimator_spec_fn
    losses_fn(features, mode, params),
  File "root/workdir/code/depth_and_motion_learning/depth_motion_field_model.py", line 165, in loss_fn
    maybe_summary.histogram('PredictedDepth', predicted_depth)
  File "root/workdir/code/depth_and_motion_learning/maybe_summary.py", line 46, in histogram
    return tf.summary.histogram(*args, **kwargs)
  File "usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/summary/summary.py", line 179, in histogram
    tag=tag, values=values, name=scope)
  File "usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/gen_logging_ops.py", line 329, in histogram_summary
    "HistogramSummary", tag=tag, values=values, name=name)
  File "usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 794, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/util/deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 3357, in create_op
    attrs, op_def, compute_device)
  File "usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 3426, in _create_op_internal
    op_def=op_def)
  File "usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 1748, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()
```

And here are the logs that tf creates:

```
  Warning: To use the exr data format, please install the OpenEXR package following the instructions detailed in the README at github.com/tensorflow/graphics.
Warning: To use the threejs_vizualization, please install the colabtools package following the instructions detailed in the README at github.com/tensorflow/graphics.
I1109 01:04:31.861343 140546576783168 training_utils.py:319] Starting training with the following parameters:
{
  "model": {
    "batch_size": 2,
    "input": {
      "data_path": "../data/pinhole/stuttgart_00_processed/train.txt"
    }
  },
  "trainer": {
    "master": "",
    "max_steps": 200,
    "model_dir": "../experiment/pinhole_test/20_gpu_memory_config/"
  }
}
I1109 01:04:31.862864 140546576783168 training_utils.py:240] Estimators run config parameters:
{
  "keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours": 10000,
  "log_step_count_steps": 10,
  "model_dir": "../experiment/pinhole_test/20_gpu_memory_config/",
  "save_summary_steps": 10
}

INFO:tensorflow:Using config: {'_model_dir': '../experiment/pinhole_test/20_gpu_memory_config/', '_tf_random_seed': None, '_save_summary_steps': 10, '_save_checkpoints_steps': None, '_save_checkpoints_secs': 600, '_session_config': gpu_options {
  per_process_gpu_memory_fraction: 0.4
}
, '_keep_checkpoint_max': 5, '_keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours': 10000, '_log_step_count_steps': 10, '_train_distribute': None, '_device_fn': None, '_protocol': None, '_eval_distribute': None, '_experimental_distribute': None, '_experimental_max_worker_delay_secs': None, '_session_creation_timeout_secs': 7200, '_service': None, '_cluster_spec': <tensorflow.python.training.server_lib.ClusterSpec object at 0x7fd353088780>, '_task_type': 'worker', '_task_id': 0, '_global_id_in_cluster': 0, '_master': '', '_evaluation_master': '', '_is_chief': True, '_num_ps_replicas': 0, '_num_worker_replicas': 1}
I1109 01:04:34.765851 140546576783168 estimator.py:212] Using config: {'_model_dir': '../experiment/pinhole_test/20_gpu_memory_config/', '_tf_random_seed': None, '_save_summary_steps': 10, '_save_checkpoints_steps': None, '_save_checkpoints_secs': 600, '_session_config': gpu_options {
  per_process_gpu_memory_fraction: 0.4
}
, '_keep_checkpoint_max': 5, '_keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours': 10000, '_log_step_count_steps': 10, '_train_distribute': None, '_device_fn': None, '_protocol': None, '_eval_distribute': None, '_experimental_distribute': None, '_experimental_max_worker_delay_secs': None, '_session_creation_timeout_secs': 7200, '_service': None, '_cluster_spec': <tensorflow.python.training.server_lib.ClusterSpec object at 0x7fd353088780>, '_task_type': 'worker', '_task_id': 0, '_global_id_in_cluster': 0, '_master': '', '_evaluation_master': '', '_is_chief': True, '_num_ps_replicas': 0, '_num_worker_replicas': 1}
2022-11-09 01:04:34.766747: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2022-11-09 01:04:34.775816: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 2198485000 Hz
2022-11-09 01:04:34.776397: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x5cc0f40 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2022-11-09 01:04:34.776439: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2022-11-09 01:04:34.779339: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2022-11-09 01:04:35.120480: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x5c14430 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2022-11-09 01:04:35.120558: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Tesla V100-DGXS-32GB, Compute Capability 7.0
2022-11-09 01:04:35.121308: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1618] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: Tesla V100-DGXS-32GB major: 7 minor: 0 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.53
pciBusID: 0000:0e:00.0
2022-11-09 01:04:35.121680: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.0
2022-11-09 01:04:35.123773: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10.0
2022-11-09 01:04:35.125422: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10.0
2022-11-09 01:04:35.125838: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10.0
2022-11-09 01:04:35.128652: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10.0
2022-11-09 01:04:35.131300: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10.0
2022-11-09 01:04:35.137281: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2022-11-09 01:04:35.145177: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1746] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2022-11-09 01:04:35.145289: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.0
2022-11-09 01:04:35.146147: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1159] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2022-11-09 01:04:35.146178: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1165]      0 
2022-11-09 01:04:35.146193: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1178] 0:   N 
2022-11-09 01:04:35.146983: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1304] Created TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0 with 30591 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla V100-DGXS-32GB, pci bus id: 0000:0e:00.0, compute capability: 7.0)
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/training_util.py:236: Variable.initialized_value (from tensorflow.python.ops.variables) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use Variable.read_value. Variables in 2.X are initialized automatically both in eager and graph (inside tf.defun) contexts.
W1109 01:04:35.160021 140546576783168 deprecation.py:323] From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/training_util.py:236: Variable.initialized_value (from tensorflow.python.ops.variables) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use Variable.read_value. Variables in 2.X are initialized automatically both in eager and graph (inside tf.defun) contexts.
2022-11-09 01:04:36.176646: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1618] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: Tesla V100-DGXS-32GB major: 7 minor: 0 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.53
pciBusID: 0000:0e:00.0
2022-11-09 01:04:36.176771: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.0
2022-11-09 01:04:36.176822: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10.0
2022-11-09 01:04:36.176868: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10.0
2022-11-09 01:04:36.176912: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10.0
2022-11-09 01:04:36.176949: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10.0
2022-11-09 01:04:36.176993: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10.0
2022-11-09 01:04:36.177038: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2022-11-09 01:04:36.177916: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1746] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
WARNING:tensorflow:From /root/workdir/code/depth_and_motion_learning/dataset/reader_cityscapes.py:175: to_float (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.cast` instead.
W1109 01:04:36.187831 140546576783168 deprecation.py:323] From /root/workdir/code/depth_and_motion_learning/dataset/reader_cityscapes.py:175: to_float (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.cast` instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /root/workdir/code/depth_and_motion_learning/dataset/reader_cityscapes.py:179: to_int32 (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.cast` instead.
W1109 01:04:36.194607 140546576783168 deprecation.py:323] From /root/workdir/code/depth_and_motion_learning/dataset/reader_cityscapes.py:179: to_int32 (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.cast` instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:Entity <function input_fn.<locals>.key_to_index at 0x7fd386508d90> could not be transformed and will be executed as-is. Please report this to the AutoGraph team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output. Cause: Cell is empty
W1109 01:04:36.220945 140546576783168 ag_logging.py:146] Entity <function input_fn.<locals>.key_to_index at 0x7fd386508d90> could not be transformed and will be executed as-is. Please report this to the AutoGraph team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output. Cause: Cell is empty
INFO:tensorflow:Calling model_fn.
I1109 01:04:41.505221 140546576783168 estimator.py:1148] Calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
I1109 01:04:42.226606 140546576783168 regularizers.py:98] Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py:1417: Layer.apply (from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.base_layer) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please use `layer.__call__` method instead.
W1109 01:04:42.229701 140546576783168 deprecation.py:323] From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py:1417: Layer.apply (from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.base_layer) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please use `layer.__call__` method instead.
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
I1109 01:04:42.564963 140546576783168 regularizers.py:98] Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
INFO:tensorflow:Summary name Learning Rate is illegal; using Learning_Rate instead.
I1109 01:04:44.232239 140546576783168 summary_op_util.py:66] Summary name Learning Rate is illegal; using Learning_Rate instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/math_grad.py:1424: where (from tensorflow.python.ops.array_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.where in 2.0, which has the same broadcast rule as np.where
W1109 01:04:44.876479 140546576783168 deprecation.py:323] From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/math_grad.py:1424: where (from tensorflow.python.ops.array_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.where in 2.0, which has the same broadcast rule as np.where
INFO:tensorflow:Done calling model_fn.
I1109 01:04:51.152709 140546576783168 estimator.py:1150] Done calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Create CheckpointSaverHook.
I1109 01:04:51.154876 140546576783168 basic_session_run_hooks.py:541] Create CheckpointSaverHook.
INFO:tensorflow:Graph was finalized.
I1109 01:04:54.262260 140546576783168 monitored_session.py:240] Graph was finalized.
2022-11-09 01:04:54.263769: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1618] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: Tesla V100-DGXS-32GB major: 7 minor: 0 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.53
pciBusID: 0000:0e:00.0
2022-11-09 01:04:54.263849: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.0
2022-11-09 01:04:54.263877: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10.0
2022-11-09 01:04:54.263897: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10.0
2022-11-09 01:04:54.263916: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10.0
2022-11-09 01:04:54.263939: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10.0
2022-11-09 01:04:54.263957: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10.0
2022-11-09 01:04:54.263977: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2022-11-09 01:04:54.264557: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1746] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2022-11-09 01:04:54.264596: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1159] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2022-11-09 01:04:54.264612: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1165]      0 
2022-11-09 01:04:54.264622: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1178] 0:   N 
2022-11-09 01:04:54.265237: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1304] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 30591 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla V100-DGXS-32GB, pci bus id: 0000:0e:00.0, compute capability: 7.0)
INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.
I1109 01:04:58.935527 140546576783168 session_manager.py:500] Running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
I1109 01:04:59.189059 140546576783168 session_manager.py:502] Done running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 0 into ../experiment/pinhole_test/20_gpu_memory_config/model.ckpt.
I1109 01:05:07.777225 140546576783168 basic_session_run_hooks.py:606] Saving checkpoints for 0 into ../experiment/pinhole_test/20_gpu_memory_config/model.ckpt.
2022-11-09 01:05:18.809505: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10.0
2022-11-09 01:05:21.801423: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 1.1412584, step = 0
I1109 01:05:26.667061 140546576783168 basic_session_run_hooks.py:262] loss = 1.1412584, step = 0
```

Comment: None of the error messages or tracebacks show out of memory problems, the traceback is also incomplete. Where do you get that there are memory problems?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Well I'm not exactly sure about it, but while it runs perfectly on CPU if `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=-1` is set, but as soon as I use a GPU it crashes right at the start of the training with the above error messages, and very occasionally with `E1109 01:24:59.579468 139722383398720 basic_session_run_hooks.py:760] Model diverged with loss = NaN.` after a minute of training.   
  
Also I can't get the GPU memory usage down, according to `nvidia-smi` its at like 99%. I also found [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59337321/15842235) on stackoverflow.

Comment: That is not a memory problem, the loss is nan, not a number, means training diverged. You should edit your question because you are misleading people by saying that it is a memory issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the source of my problems might be [this bug for CUDA 10.0](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31166). I've yet to find a workaround for that that's suitable for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).